# Filter specific value on a concatenate field in DAX

Tags: if-statement, conditional-statements, powerbi, dax, powerquery

I'm not expert in DAX and Power Query language and I would need help.

I have a table similar to the following:

```
Item1 Item2 Item3 Item4 Conc_2-4
A     B     C     D     B,C,D
F     G     H     I     G,H,I
L     M     G     C     M,G,C
A     H     D     R     H,D,R
```

In my report I would like to display a table where there are only the first 4 columns (without the column `Conc_2-4`), but I would like to be able to filter the table through the column `Conc_2-4`, without this being displayed in the report.

In other words, I would like to have the distinct values of the items in the filter and when I filter a certain item, the result should return all rows in which this item is present in the columns `Item2`, `Item3`, `Item4` independently from the position.

**EXAMPLE**

If in my report I filter the item `H`, the resulting table in my report should be as follows:

```
Item1 Item2 Item3 Item4
F     G     H     I
A     H     D     R
```

Does anyone know how to solve the problem? Maybe using Power Query?

Thanks for any suggestions

Answer (score 2):

Interesting problem. I found one approach that works, but there are probably other solutions as well.

---

First, we need an index column. Go to the Query Editor and select your `Items` query. On the Add Column tab, click the Index Column button and then Close & Apply.

[image: Index Column]

Now that we have an index column, we will create a new table to act as a slicer. Go to the Modeling tab and create a New Table as follows:

```
Slicer = UNION(SELECTCOLUMNS(Items, "Item", Items[Item2], "Index", Items[Index]), 
               SELECTCOLUMNS(Items, "Item", Items[Item3], "Index", Items[Index]),
               SELECTCOLUMNS(Items, "Item", Items[Item4], "Index", Items[Index]))
```

Now under the Relationships screen, create a relationship between the index columns on the two table making sure that the cross-directional filtering applies both ways.

[image: Relationship]

That's it! Now you should be able to create a table and slicer that behaves like you specified.

[image: Slicer and Table]